# How to avoid lags when listening to music on a Mac?

Tags: macos, command-line, music, performance, mplayer

On a Mac 10.13.6 I am usually listening to music using the command line command `mplayer`. However, when the computer is under rather heavy load, the music sometimes stops for a fraction of a second up to a second (or even longer) all the time.

The music is mp3 files stored locally and I’m guessing the CPU scheduling to priority is what is causing this interruption. In my use case, everything else the computer is doing is less relevant so I want to promote this app to the best performance.

The version is:

> MPlayer 1.3.0-4.2.1

Can I change how I run this app to avoid slowdowns when the CPU gets busy?

Answer (score 1):

Check out nice and renice which work on the command line.

You can change the priority level of processes, but to change other users processes you have to be admin level...

Just to provide a link with examples, see https://www.lifewire.com/uses-of-commands-nice-renice-2201087

Comment: I think I tried that already without any noticeable change of the behavior. I assume because its a mac...?

Comment: I just tried again with `nice -n -20 mplayer ...` and it happens again.

Comment: Ok, sorry, if I think of something else I will post it.

Comment: I should have mentioned I tried with `nice`. But now it happened again, although I am not doing a astrophysical simulation of the Einstein equations. (I am just re-encoding a video...)

Comment: About the same thing for the processor :) handbrake always makes mine work hard... Have you tried renice-ing handbrake to slow it down? ie reduce its load... makes it longer though...

Comment: I don’t think nice values have had any scheduling input since 10.5 or 10.6 days, but I don’t have an authorticave article. Yes, in old school theory of UNIX scheduling, this would be the answer, but I’m pretty sure you won’t get any measurable effect on a modern macOS / iOS / watchOS / tvOS system by trying to nice a process.

Comment: So it is because its a mac ;-)

Comment: I might try a handbrake task and see if renice makes a difference... just out of interest - as nice & renice used to work fine in practise, not theory, on the SGI machines when running loooong cfd jobs...